# Change of Reeb orbits after scaling the contact form

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, contact-geometry

Let $M$ be a contact manifold with a contact form $\theta$ with Reeb vector field $X$ and $f$ be a positive function on $M$. If $\mathcal{L}_X f\neq 0$ the Reeb vector field $X'$ of $\theta'=f \theta$ will not be a multiple of $X$. My question is: How much of the topology of the Reeb orbits changes? For example, can it happen that the number of closed Reeb orbits of $X$ and $X'$ are different? An example would be appreciated.

Comment: To give you an idea of how much things change, just think that on the spherized cotangent bundle to a manifold $M$ (the bundle of cotangent directions), the contact forms associated to any two Riemannian (or even Finsler metrics) are such multiples. On the $2$-sphere you can go from all geodesics are closed to ergodic geodesic flow, to only two geodesics are closed.

Answer (score 3):

The dynamics can change quite drastically. (There are more subtle things one can say about dynamics on contact manifolds; e.g. for closed contact 3-manifolds there are always [at least two periodic Reeb orbits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4839) (and it is conjectured that there are either two or infinitely many orbits with no in between, which has been [proven in the generic case](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.01448)). But I will not address these points.)

First, a helpful simplification. By Gray stability, you don't need to restrict to changes of the form $\theta' = f\theta$: if you study deformations $\theta_t$ (with $\theta_0 = \theta$) through contact forms, you can find a diffeotopy $\phi_t$ (with $\phi_0 = id$) so that $\theta_t = f_t\phi_t^*\theta$ for some family of positive functions $f_t$. So if the Reeb dynamics change drastically for such a deformation of $\theta$ (not necessarily of the form $\theta_t = (tf+1)\theta$ or something similar), then you have an answer to your question.

***Example***
A standard example is the following (Geiges' *An Introduction to Contact Topology* Example 2.2.5): Consider on $S^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ the contact form given by the restriction of $$\theta_t = (x_1dy_1 - y_1dx_1) + (1+t)(x_2dy_2 - y_2dx_2)$$ to $S^3$ for $t > -1$. Then the Reeb vector field is $$R_t = (x_1\partial_{y_1} - y_1\partial x_1) + \frac{1}{1+t}(x_2\partial_{y_2} - y_2\partial_{x_2})$$ which preserves the decomposition $$S^3 = \bigcup_{0 \leq C \leq 1} T_C$$ where $T_C$ are the tori $$T_C = \{|x_1|^2+|y_1|^2 = C, |x_2|^2+|y_2|^2 = 1-C\} \subset S^3.$$ (When $C=0,1$, we just have circles.) If $t \in \mathbb{Q}$, then on each $T_C$, we just have the flow by translation along a line of rational slope, and so we get that each $T_C$ is foliated by Reeb orbits. If $t \notin \mathbb{Q}$, then we are flowing with irrational slope, so there are only two Reeb orbits, the degenerate "tori" $T_0$ and $T_1$.

***Same example, with appeal to Gray stability removed:***
If you want to translate this into the non-Gray-ified version, where you're just scaling $\theta_0$ on the nose, then notice that $\psi_t \colon S^3 \rightarrow S^3$ given by $$\psi_t(x_1,y_1;x_2,y_2) = \frac{(x_1,y_1,x_2\sqrt{1+t},y_2\sqrt{1+t})}{\sqrt{1+t(x_2^2+y_2^2)}}$$ satisfies $$\frac{1}{1+t(x_2^2+y_2^2)}\psi_t^*\theta_0 = \theta_t.$$ In other words, $\psi_t$ allows us to conflate the dynamics of $\theta_t$ with those of $\frac{1}{1+t(x_2^2+y_2^2)}\theta_0$.

***Side Note:*** If you're curious about how this mysterious $\psi_t$ appears, the point is that these are constructed by considering the ellipsoids $$E_t = \left\{|x_1|^2+|y_1|^2 + \frac{|x_2|^2+|y_2|^2}{1+t}\right\} \subset \mathbb{R}^4.$$ We have that on $\mathbb{R}^4$, any star-shaped hypersurface $H$ is contact with respect to the restriction of $\lambda = (x_1dy_1 - y_1dx_1) + (x_2dy_2 - y_2dx_2)$, and the radial projection $H \cong S^3$ induces a contactomorphism. Hence, we have a radial contactomorphism $$\phi_1 \colon (S^3,\ker\lambda|_{S^3}) \xrightarrow{\sim} (\partial E_t,\ker \lambda|_{\partial E_t}),$$ i.e. with $\phi_1^* (\lambda|_{\partial E_t}) = f_t\lambda|_{S^3} = f_t\theta_0$. On the other hand, we have the isomorphism $$\phi_2 \colon S^3 \xrightarrow{\sim} \partial E_t$$ given by dilating the $(x_2,y_2)$-coordinates, and $\theta_t$ is just defined as $\phi_2^* (\lambda|_{E_t})$. Our $\psi_t$ is just $\phi_1^{-1} \circ \phi_2$.

***Generic statement:***
Generically, you can make all Reeb orbits non-degenerate, which is a condition implying that no orbit has a nearby Reeb orbit of similar action. The point is that $\theta' = e^f\theta$ has Reeb field $$R_{\theta'} = \frac{1}{e^f}(R_{\theta} + X_f)$$ where $X_f$ is the unique vector field in $\ker \theta$ such that $d\theta(X_f,Y) = df(Y)$ for all $Y \in \ker \theta$, and so one can argue that any Reeb orbit can be made non-degenerate by choosing $f$ supported near that Reeb orbit appropriately. (C.f. Lemma 2 of Bourgeois' [*Introduction to Contact Homology*](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ebourgeois/papers/Berder.pdf).) In particular, the $t\in \mathbb{Q}$ case for our $S^3$ example is non-generic because none of the Reeb orbits are isolated. There are many many more examples of non-isolated Reeb orbits: prequantization/Boothby-Wang bundles, the standard contact form $-\cos(z)dx+\sin(z)dy$ on $T^3 = S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$, etc. For all of them, a generic perturbation will kill this isolation.